# Write the Labels code in Standard way

Tags: magento-1.9

We are Displaying code as below format in view.phtml file. Instead of just entering "Product Description" , is there any **magento standard way** to write code to display "Product Description"

```
<div class="tabs active" onclick="changeTab(0)">Product Description</div>
<div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(1)">Features</div>
<div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(2)">Reviews</div>
<div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(3)">Add Review</div
```

I am not sure,  this question make sense or not, but client said the code is not in standard way of magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not translating the labels.
They need to be like this:

```
<div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(1)"><?php echo $this->__('Features');?></div>
```

Comment: This is top class, yes i am excpecting this way. thanks a lot.....